# Виды баз данных и их классификация

Tags: sql, база-данных

Ознакомился с видами баз данных на разных ресурсах:
**Википедия:**

- Иерархическая
- Объектная и объектно-ориентированная
- Объектно-реляционная
- Реляционная
- Сетевая
- Функциональная

Решил посмотреть **видео**, наткнулся на видео (где были хорошие комментарии) и много лайков, где показывались такие виды:

- Фактографическая
- Документальная
- Распределённая
- Централизованная
- Реляционная

Еще я наткнулся на ресурс где были другие виды, у меня вопрос: 
Так на какие виды делятся базы данных, то есть какие базы данных существуют?

Comment: всё будет зависеть от критерия, по которому вы их разделяете

Answer (score 1):

Классификация зависит от выбранного критерия. Если отойти от базы данных, а взять предметы вокруг вас, вы можете их классифицировать: по цвету(зеленые, желтые, красные), по форме (квадратные, круглые), по съедобности (съедобные, несъедобные), по материалу (железные, пластиковые, тканевые) и т.д.

Так же и с базами данных, вы можете их по разному классифицировать. Далее я просто перечислю некоторые примеры из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85):

Классификация по модели данных

- Иерархическая
- Объектная и объектно-ориентированная
- Объектно-реляционная
- Реляционная
- Сетевая
- Функциональная

Классификация по среде постоянного хранения

- на жестком диске
- в оперативной памяти
- на удаленных носителях
- распределенная

Классификация по содержимому

- Географическая
- Историческая
- Научная
- Мультимедийная
- Библиографическая

Обычно рассматривают по модели данных, однако в последнее время набирают популярность распределенные базы данных из-за возрастающих с каждым годом объемов данных, не умещающихся даже на массиве жестких дисков одного компьютера или дороговизны этих самых массивов.